# Hibernate: Strange ID Setup

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm dealing with a legacy database that uses a strange key/ID configuration for one of its tables.  It's the table that defines user information.  Here are the columns (I've simplified things a little):

```
ID
Secondary ID
First Name
Last Name
Change Type
```

All of these columns are part of the key in the database itself and are needed to uniquely identify a row, with one exception.  When the Change Type column has a null value then the ID column uniquely identifies a row.  This exception is heavily relied on to get a user's name based on their ID.  However I need to specify all columns as @Id for hibernate to work correctly with this table ... or do I?  Assuming I do, how would I go about also implementing the exception so that objects can be loaded from the database by just the ID?  Ideally I'd like to be able to interact with this object as if ID was the only key since in practice that's how it's done in straight SQL by the DBAs.